# Saving Stream to Folder - fail readDirectory() errno=20

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am trying to save a stream to a subfolder of storage/emulated/0, but am getting the error `fail readDirectory() errno=20`

I am using the below code :

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(instream, buffersize);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".download"),
    buffersize);
                
int len;
int downloadedlen = 0;
byte[] buff = new byte[buffersize];
String firstfewchars = null;
while ((len = bis.read(buff)) > 0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Writing Data from Stream Line 814");
    out.write(buff, 0, len);
}
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Post your logcat

Comment: Check the actual folder you are trying to write to. Sure it isn't a writable one. Android is pretty specific about where to write data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have permissions, and folder is public?

For testing, You can try get directory in this way:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Also, don't forget permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```